# how to store data into mysql after login validation using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

i am try to store data into mysql after login validation ,but how give path of database. thank you

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
var username=$('#username').val();
var password=$('#password').val();

if((username=="")&&(password==""))
{
 $('div').html("<span>please type userpass and password</span>")    ;
}
if(username=="")
{
$('div').html("<span>Please type Username</span>");
return false;
}
if(password=="")
{
$('div').html('<span id="error">Please type Password</span>');
return false;
}

});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="color:red"></div>
User Name <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/><br/>
Password <input type="text" id="password" name="password"/><br/>
<button ">Get JSON data</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In short; jquery runs on your client's browser, you just don't want to open your mysql to the whole wide world.

Instead create an backend api or so to both verify given credentials and to store validation data if required.

There are thousands of examples on the web, here is one http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/ (don't know if this is the best possible example, but at least wide and detailed so you can get the understanding of what you are wanting to do.